# Master/Slave workflow utilizing pre compiled binaries as Slaves in Fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmp, ipc, zeromq

I have the following use case at the moment.

1. Master starts and reads in a control file. This file contains information about which Slaves should be used in this run. Each user has the ability to write their own Slaves and add them to the list. The Slaves used in each run varies. It is not feasible to recompile the Master between each run to add/subtract slaves.
2. Master prints the data needed for the next Slave to a file.
3. Master starts the Slave (a slave being a *separate program*) which in turn reads the data from file, processes it, and prints it back to the file.
4. Master reads the data from the file.
5. If the list of tasks is done, Master writes the result to file and stops, otherwise the next task is started and the process returns to 2.

As you see, this is not super efficient. The read/write performed each time the Master or a Slave is started is a bottleneck in the flow. Especially since there are usually +25 tasks on the list, each with a separate Slave to perform the task. Because of this I have been looking at leaving the "file" system and migrate to something better. I have tried using pipes, which is slightly better, and sockets (writing a client/server communication system in C that is called by my Fortran programs). I have also looked into both OpenMP, MPI and ZeroMQ (I did not get ZeroMQ to work with Fortran at all) with various results. One could argue that the whole program should be rewritten each time a Slave is added or subtracted, but we are talking millions of lines that would have to be recompiled each time.

Now, I turn to the community with the question: Given what I have said above (where each Slave is called after one another and only communicates via the Master (i.e. Master -> Slave1 -> Master -> Slave2 -> Master -> SlaveN -> Master)) does any way of communicating between the Master and the Slaves come across as more or less wise?

Cheers

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, edited for clarity.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, as can be read under list point 3 (and as the title hints), each slave is a separate program that is started by the Master. Since the Slaves are _not_ subroutines, I have been looking at different ways to perform IPC between the Master and the various Slaves.

Comment: The issue here being that it is not feasible to recompile the Master every time a Slave is added or subtracted from the workflow. The slaves varies between each run and users can write their own Slaves and invoke these using the aforementioned control file.

Comment: as @HighPerformanceMark, your problem is very unclear. 1) is the task k+1 dependent on the completion of task k? What do you mean by inneficient?

Comment: @innoSPG, I thought it was quite clear that Slave2 cannot be started until Master calls it (after Slave1 is completed) as illustrated by: _[...] where each Slave is called after one another and only communicates via the Master (i.e. Master -> Slave1 -> Master -> Slave2 -> Master -> SlaveN -> Master)_, but I am sorry if that was not the case. Regardless, the slaves need to be run in sequence. What I mean by inefficient is that the I/O performed r/w data is slow in comparison to using e.g. sockets to pass the data between the Master and the Slave.

Comment: @GLaDER are you aware of dynamic libraries? You can load a dynamic library provided by a user and call it like it was a function "compiled" (actually linked) into your master.

Comment: @Zulan, I have never heard of this. Is it a Fortran feature or *nix?

Comment: I do not know how exactly to use it in Fortran, but it is more-or-less language agnostic (like linking in general). On Posix systems you are looking for `dlopen`. In general, you should read up on the difference between compiling and linking. You are making the wrong assumptions (i.e. you have to recompile all your code every time you change something). Unfortunately I think your use case is still too vague to give a really good answer. For instance please clarify what role parallelism plays in your use-case. Do you have a distributed system? Shared memory? Do you need multi-threading?

Comment: @Zulan, I'll look into it. Regarding your questions I really don't need anything but being able to pass the data between the Master and the Slave more efficiently. I am currently writing tens of thousands of bytes each iteration (Master -> Slave -> Master) and it would be useful to speed up that process. I have no intention to use the multi threading ability of any of the APIs above, I just want the ability to pass data between two processes.

Comment: Have you actually measured the efficiency of your approach? How long is one iteration? 10 KB of data is very small. What is your operating system. You could use [`/dev/shm`](http://superuser.com/questions/45342/when-should-i-use-dev-shm-and-when-should-i-use-tmp). Or pipes. Or sockets... there are so many IPC mechanisms out there.

Comment: @GLaDER, thanks for the reply, I actually saw in your flowchart the dependency, but nothing indicated that it was necessary. The suggestion of zulan is an option. But I think that it might be better to stay off that approach especially if security is (or might get) involved. What I mean is that the master can have access to system resources that you do not want slaves to access, because they might be untrusted. If those slave are encapsulated into libraries called by the master, I do not know if it is easy to control that. While if they are started as independent programs, you can restrict.

Comment: Now the problem is, is the data transmission the problem? or the problem is the overhead system call to start new process? If the problem is really the data transmission you can use file mapping, that maps the file into memory. That way, you have little modifications to do to your existing code.

Comment: For your problems with ZeroMQ, please post an issue here: https://github.com/zeromq/f77_zmq/issues and I will be glad to help.

Comment: @Zulan, running the whole program takes hours and we have estimated that reducing I/O by a factor 5 or more (which seems to be the advantage by switching to sockets) is well worth it.

Comment: @innoSPG, I will lookinto file mapping!

Comment: @AnthonyScemama, I contacted you on the gitter-link provided in your repository. Now, I have also submitted an issue.

Comment: Are you transferring formatted (human readable) or unformatted (binary blob) data between the programs?

Comment: @IanH, formatted data.

Comment: Transferring unformatted data will make the io component of the master/slave transitions materially faster.  Many of the ephemeral storage options (and which can be used in combination with transferring unformatted data) that you are considering are going to make it quite difficult for a human to read the data as it is transferred anyway.